Why is "Set as Top-Level Entity" grayed out in quartus?
I am new to hardware design using System Verilog, so I'm trying to compile a very very simple file: a  D Flip Flop.
it consists of the following code (taken from https://www.chipverify.com/verilog/verilog-modules):
//examples of module declaration

//here i will make a very simple d flip flop

//declaring a new component that will contain some logic
module dff(input d, input clk, input rstn, output reg q);

always @ (posedge clk) 
begin
if(!rstn)
    q <= 0;
else
    q <= d;
    
end

endmodule

Whenever I go to compile I get the error
Error (12007): Top-level design entity "basics_of_verilog" is undefined
This makes sense. As my module "DFF" is named completely differently from the top level entity I declared at project creation.
However, I cannot set DFF to be the new top level entity. As the button to actually do it is greyed out.
(https://i.sstatic.net/aFfC1.png)
I have never seen this before, can someone tell me what exactly is going on here? I've been scratching my head at this for a few minutes.
I already tried googling the error, but it seems that I'm the first person in recorded human history to encounter this error (I should get a nobel prize for this).

i tried implementing a one bit adder using the following source: https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~traylor/ece474/beamer_lectures/verilog_modules.pdf
however, same issue occurs. cant set as top level entity.

Your screenshot is hiding all the details in the tool. Do you have multiple files in a project and you're trying to make "dff.sv" as the top module?
If so, there is a tab "Files" next to  the "hierarchy", in that tab, you'll see all the files in the project. Right click on a file and choose "Set as top module", the tool should allow. or share another screenshot, I'll point where the tabs are

I found the solution.
For some reason, the option to make a current design file the top level hierarchy by selecting project > "Set as Top-Level Entity" is unavailable at times.
I got around this by doing the following: go into the project navigator window, then select the "hierarchy" drop down box. https://snipboard.io/2CyP4r.jpg then, right click on the file you wanna set as the top level hierarchy and select "Set as Top-Level Entity" https://snipboard.io/4kLheM.jpg
This fixed it. Props to Tushar for providing this solution!

I am glad you got your issue resolved; however your solution does not an answer the posted question Why is "Set as Top-Level Entity" grayed out in quartus?  It looks like you are saying the answer to the posted question is For some reason.

The reason why its grayed out is still unknown. And honestly it makes no sense since you can still set it as the top level entity via the project navigator.
